# SSIS Error Output

Tags: ssis

Consider this Transformation

```
OLE DB Source > 

 Look up Transformation > 

          Match Records > OLE DB Command [Update Statement]
          No Match Records > OLE Destination [Insert]
```

I wanted to redirect the error rows from both the transformations to the same error log, is there a way to do it?

Regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect error outputs to the same union all and then write into destination table.

Perhaps You would like to add derived column to make distinction of rows coming from those error outputs. (if there is no any other column that could be used for this purpose)

Comment: Thanks Filip, that worked i added a union all transformation that combined both the error outputs and redirected that to the log file.